# How to match only part of a word with regex entity?

Tags: regex, entity, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to extract house numbers from (Dutch) addresses using the following regex entity: 
[(?:re\Bstraat)\s\d+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBJCu.png)

It's supposed to find numbers that come after "straat" but only if straat does not have a word boundary, i.e. it's supposed to match:

"straat 78" in kerkstraat 78

However, I'm running into two problems. Firstly I am only interested in the number, not the street that comes before it. I thought using a noncapturing group would solve that but I'm not sure I'm using that correctly.

Secondly, Dialogflow only lets me select whole words in training phrases. When I try to select only "straat 65" in Wilhelminastraat 65 for example, the selection just snaps to the whole word [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UptNX.png). But then it tells me that the annotated text does not correspond to the entity type.

**Edit:**
I think what I was looking for was `(?<=\Bstraat\s)(\d+)`. Unfortunately lookaround is not supported by Dialogflow according to the documentation, so what I'm trying to do seems to be impossible (without fulfillment).

Comment: Try `\Bstraat\s+(\d+)`

Comment: Why? that doesn't address the problem of being unable to select only part of a word, and like I said I used a noncapturing group because I'm only interested in the number

Comment: Non-capturing groups still consume text. If it is RE2, you can't use a regex to "exclude" text from match. Capturing groups are usually meant for this

Comment: I think what I was looking for was (?<=\Bstraat\s)(\d+). Unfortunately lookaround is not supported by Dialogflow according to the documentation, so what I'm trying to do seems to be impossible (without fulfillment).

Comment: did you try creating a composite entity? or just take the whole string as input with @sys.any and programmatically extract address using regex.

Comment: Since you are only interested in the number, would just using an integer entity not be enough? It adds the danger of picking up other integers, but looking at your training data, you are only training it to understand sentences with just house numbers.

Comment: @Jordi, no, the intent that I made was just a test for the regex. The actual intent I want to use it for can include other numbers.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi Thanks, I will try composite entities. I know I could use fulfillment, but I'm trying to move away from that for entity extraction because we are running into issues with Dialogflows limit of 3 followupEvents